# got parse error on input `=>' on Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax

```
bmiTell :: => Double -> String
bmiTell bmi
    | bmi <= 18.5 = "You're underweight, you emo, you!"
    | bmi <= 25.0 = "You're supposeldly normal. Pffft, I bet you're ugly!"
    | bmi <= 30.0 = "You're fat! Lose some weight, fatty!"
    | otherwise   = "You are a whale, congratulations!"
```

This code got me an error, "parse error on input '=>'"
I have no idea why.
Any help?
thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line:

```
bmiTell :: => Double -> String
```

Has the symbol `=>`, which is used to separate out class constraints from the signature containing constrained types.  However, you don't have any constraints, nothing such as `Show a =>`.  The solution?  Delete it!

```
bmiTell :: Double -> String
```